# C++ Вызов деструкторов объектов и очистка памяти после realloc

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы, деструктор, realloc

Всем привет! Вопрос чисто теоретический: Есть ли в С++ аналог realloc из ванильного Си? Чтобы можно было менять размеры массива?
И смежный вопрос: будут ли правильно(т.е. с вызовом деструкторов) удаляться объекты при вызове delete[] array,если перед этим было array=realloc(....) ? И если нет, то как решить эту проблему?
P.S. я знаю,что есть волшебный std::vector, но меня очень интересует реализация без примочек из STL.

Comment: без "примочек" из STL. С++ теряет смысл.  "волшебный" std::vector   всего лишь один из классов _ контейнеров, есть и много других. без "примочек" из STL, можете сами написать нужный вам  класс.  Деструкторы вызываются перед уничтожением объектов, а  не наоборот.   Нельзя создавать объекты с помощью  сишных функций, а удалять  С++ оператором.   Почему вам не брать учебник и изучать нормально?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan дело в том, что я прекрасно знаю,что нельзя смешивать, как говорится, бульдога с носорогом,  поэтому и задал вопрос, но как иначе удлинять массив, с учётом того,что вариант stl не подходит? Ну считайте что у меня аллергия на нее)

Comment: Вы могли бы забыть про аллергию и   смотреть как они реализованы.  А все просто: если создан array = new Type[N], то  при перераспределении нужно учитывать берется память больше или меньше?  Для нового значения  M   _ if (M > N) { delete [] array...;  array = new Type[M] и т.д. и т.п., то есть все делать в ручную или написать свой класс, деструктор которого выполняет удаление(тогда вы там все напишете в ручную) . Написать распределитель памяти или пользоваться стандартным,  применить умные указатели... Вариантов много, если не хотите написать удаление сами.

Comment: Библиотека существует  для того, чтобы вы ориентировались на действительных и важных проблемах проекта, а не буксовали  на устаревших проблемах. А если цель учебная, тогда лучше хорошо изучать учебники и задать стоящий вопрос

Comment: Нет. Нет. Переписать некоторые куски стандартной библиотеки (отслеживание размера массива, выделение новой памяти, перенос объектов etc — словом, написать свой вектор).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы понять, почему нельзя перемешивать "сишные" `malloc()`/`realloc()`/`free()` и "плюсовые" `new()`/`delete()`/`new[]()`/`delete[]()`, надо понимать принципиальную разницу между этими двумя способами работы с динамической памятью. А разница эта заключается в том, что `malloc()`/`realloc()`/`free()` работают с голой памятью, в то время, как операторы `new` и `delete` имеют дело уже с объектами, для которых дополнительно вызываются цепочки конструкторов и деструкторов.

Когда создаётся динамический массив объектов, то оператор `new[]` делает следующее:

1. Выделяет память под массив (для этого, как правило, вызывается обычная `malloc()`). Если память выделить не удалось, бросает исключение `std::bad_alloc()`.
2. Если объекты заданного типа имеют нетривиальный конструктор (отличный от того, что по умолчанию), то вызывает в цикле конструктор для каждого объекта в массиве.

Оператор `delete[]`, соответственно, действует наоборот:

1. Если объекты заданного типа имеют нетривиальный деструктор, то в обратном цикле (справа налево) вызывает деструктор для каждого объекта.
2. Освобождает память (вызвав `free()`).

И вот тут должен возникнуть вопрос: а откуда оператор `delete[]` собственно узнаёт длину массива? Ведь в качестве аргумента этому оператору передаётся только указатель! А ответ прост: если существует нетривиальный деструктор, то оператор `new[]` выделяет память не только под массив, но и под его длину, определённым образом сохраняет эту длину в выделенную область и возвращает *смещённый* указатель! И это только одна из причин, почему нельзя вызывать `free()` и `realloc()` для указателя, который был получен с помощью `new[]` - потому что этот указатель может оказаться *смещённым* по отношению к тому адресу, который возвратила `malloc()` внутри оператора `new[]`!

И так: существует ли аналог `realloc()` для вариантов с `new[]` и `delete[]`? Ну например, какой-нибудь гипотетический оператор `renew Type[new_length]`. Увы, нет такого оператора. Можно ли реализовать нечто похожее без использования `std::vector`? Можно, но для этого придётся всё равно написать собственный аналог `std::vector`.

Ниже я набросал демку, реализующую шаблонный класс `CDynamicArray`, который имеет три основных метода: `New()`, `ReNew()` и `Delete()`, а также перегружает некоторые операторы, мимикрируя под обычный массив. `ReNew()`, как нетрудно догадаться, действует, как аналог `realloc()` Можно сказать, что прога демонстрирует принципы, по которым работает сам `std::vector`, так что думаю, полезно будет к ознакомлению. И да, может содержать ошибки, хоть я и отладил (если кто найдёт, просьба указать).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <new>

//Шаблонный класс-велосипед, реализует динамический массив, похожий по поведению на std::vector
template <typename TData>
class CDynamicArray
{
    TData*  m_pArray;
    size_t  m_length;

    void _copy_array(CDynamicArray* pSrcArray)
    {
        m_length = pSrcArray->m_length;

        if (m_length)
        {
            TData* pCopy = (TData*)malloc(m_length*sizeof(TData));
            if (!pCopy) throw std::bad_alloc();
            for (TData *pDst=pCopy, *pSrc=pSrcArray->m_pArray, *pEnd = pCopy+m_length; pDst<pEnd; ++pDst,++pSrc)
            {
                //вызываем конструктор копирования (palacement new)
                new(pDst) TData(*pSrc);
            }
            m_pArray = pCopy;
            return;
        }

        m_pArray = nullptr;
    }

    void _delete()
    {
        TData* pDst = m_pArray + m_length;
        while (pDst > m_pArray) (--pDst)->~TData(); //вызываем деструктор напрямую
        free(m_pArray);                             //освобождаем память
    }

public:
    CDynamicArray(): m_pArray(nullptr), m_length(0)     {}
    template <typename... TArgs> CDynamicArray(size_t length, TArgs... args): m_length(0) {New(length,args...);}
    CDynamicArray(CDynamicArray& rSrcArray)             {_copy_array(&rSrcArray);}
    CDynamicArray& operator=(CDynamicArray& rSrcArray)  {_delete(); _copy_array(&rSrcArray); return *this;}
    ~CDynamicArray() {_delete();}

    template <typename... TArgs> void New(size_t length, TArgs... args)
    {
        if (m_length) _delete();

        if (length)
        {
            TData* pArray = (TData*)malloc(length*sizeof(TData));
            if (!pArray) throw std::bad_alloc();

            for (TData *pDst=pArray, *pEnd = pArray+length; pDst<pEnd; ++pDst)
            {
                //вызываем конструктор (palacement new)
                new(pDst) TData(args...);
            }

            m_pArray = pArray;
            m_length = length;
            return;
        }

        m_pArray = nullptr;
        m_length = 0;
    }

    template <typename... TArgs> void ReNew(size_t new_length, TArgs... args)
    {
        if (new_length != m_length)
        {
            TData* pNewArray = (TData*)malloc(new_length*sizeof(TData));
            if (!pNewArray) throw std::bad_alloc();

            size_t min_length = (new_length > m_length)? m_length: new_length;
            TData* pSrc = m_pArray;
            TData* pDst = pNewArray;
            TData* pDstEnd = pNewArray + min_length;

            //копируем объекты в новую область
            for (; pDst<pDstEnd; ++pDst,++pSrc) new(pDst) TData(*pSrc);  

            if (new_length > m_length)
            {
                //создаём новые объекты
                pDstEnd = pNewArray + new_length;
                for (; pDst<pDstEnd; ++pDst) new(pDst) TData(args...);
            }

            //удаляем старый массив
            _delete();

            m_pArray = pNewArray;
            m_length = new_length;
        }
    }

    void Delete()
    {
        _delete();
        m_pArray = nullptr;
        m_length = 0;
    }

    TData* GetArray()           {return m_pArray;}
    size_t GetLength()          {return m_length;}
    TData& operator[](int i)    {assert ((i>=0) && (i<m_length)); return m_pArray[i];}
    operator TData*()           {return m_pArray;}
    TData* operator+(int i)     {return m_pArray + i;}
};


//тестовый класс
class CTest
{
    int m_val;

public:
    CTest(int val): m_val(val)      {printf("Constructor for %d\n", m_val);}
    //CTest(CTest& rSrc): m_val(rSrc.m_val)  {printf("Copiing %d\n", m_val);}
    ~CTest()                        {printf("Destructor of %d\n", m_val);}

    int GetVal()                    {return m_val;}
};


int main()
{
    CDynamicArray<CTest> arr, arr2;

    arr.New(4, 44);
    printf("Array New:\t\t");
    for (int i=0; i<arr.GetLength(); ++i) printf("%d ", arr[i].GetVal());
    puts("\n");

    arr.ReNew(7, 77);
    printf("Array ReNew+:\t\t");
    for (CTest* p = arr; p<arr+arr.GetLength(); ++p) printf("%d ", p->GetVal());
    puts("\n");

    arr.ReNew(2, 0);
    printf("Array ReNew-:\t\t");
    for (int i=0; i<arr.GetLength(); ++i) printf("%d ", arr[i].GetVal());
    puts("\n");

    arr2 = arr;
    arr.Delete();
    printf("Array copy:\t\t");
    for (int i=0; i<arr2.GetLength(); ++i) printf("%d ", arr2[i].GetVal());
    puts("\n");

    arr2.Delete();
    return 0;
}
```

Хочу обратить внимание, что и здесь мы не можем использовать функцию `realloc()`, т.к. при переносе данных в новую область памяти, старая область становится неопределена и мы не можем вызвать деструкторы для старых копий объектов. И даже если в случае уменьшения длины массива не гарантируется, что не будет выполнен перенос памяти. Так что остаётся только одно: создавать новую область, копировать объекты из старой области, удалять старую область (с вызовом деструкторов).

Comment: "для этого, как правило, вызывается обычная malloc()" - в C++ есть пара `operator new`/`operator delete` для работы с памятью без конструирования объектов.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy если вы имеете в виду неперегруженные функции `void* operator new(size_t)` и `void operator delete(void*)`, то они внутри себя всё равно вызывают `malloc()` и `free()`. Собственно, это я и имел ввиду. Понятно, что в общем это не является неприложной истиной, однако в MinGW это так, в MS VC++ - тоже.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что ```new[]``` смещает указатель. Скорее всего он просто обращается к менеджеру памяти за этим

Comment: @Bloody.cpp зря сомневаетесь) Что делает оператор `new[]` в MinGW я подсмотрел в дизассемблере. В начало выделенной области памяти он записывает длину массива, а затем прибавляет к возвращаемому адресу `sizeof(size_t)`. Оператор `delete[]`, соответственно, отнимает эту величину и считывает длину. Такие смещения происходят только тогда, когда есть нетривиальный деструктор. Если последний отсутствует, то длина никуда не сохраняется и адрес не смещается. Не верите - дизассемблируйте)

Comment: А если деструктора нет? Какой-нибудь простой тип данных.
И если он есть, но не нужен вызов деструктора при расширении массива, как быть? Чтобы чисто освобождение памяти.

Comment: А еще, разве в методе _delete не  нужно было делать цикл c >=? А то получается для самого 1го элемента деструктор не вызовется

Comment: @Supreme Machine если деструктора/конструктора нет, то нормальный оптимизирующий компилятор должен циклы с их вызовом удалять из кода (по-хорошему, желательно ещё все методы класса `CDynamicArray` снабдить директивой `inline`, но в C++ с ней есть заморочки, по-этому здесь я её опустил). Не могу со стопроцентной гарантией ручаться за другие компиляторы, но MInGW действительно это оптимизирует, и в случае, например, простых типов данных (таких как `int`, 'float` и пр.) методы `New()` и `Delete` превращаются в обычные `malloc()` и `free()`. Полагаю, что в MS VC++ тоже так.

Comment: @Supreme Machine "разве в методе _delete не нужно было делать цикл c >=?" Не нужно! Присмотритесь, там в теле цикла - прединкремент: `(--pDst)->~TData()`;. Т.е., в последнем цикле, когда `pDst` на единицу больше `m_pArray`, он сначала уменьшается и становится указателем на первый элемент, для которого вызывается деструктор. А уже потом к нему применяется `while` и происходит выход из цикла. Но по крайней мере один косячок в своём коде я нашёл;) В методе `TData& operator[](int i)    {assert (i<m_length); return m_pArray[i];}`. Там ассерт должен выглядеть так: `assert ((i<m_length) && (i>=0));`.

Comment: @Supreme Machine "И если он есть, но не нужен вызов деструктора при расширении массива". При удалении объектов, их деструктор (если он есть) вызывается всегда. При расширении массива происходит копирование элементов в новую область памяти, старые объекты должны быть удалены. И, соответственно, их деструктор должен быть вызван. Однако можно переписать метод `ReNew()` на основе не копирования/удаления, а собственно перемещения объектов (используя `std::move() и конструкторы перемещения`). Такой подход выглядит более логичным.

Comment: ИСПРАВИЛ ОШИБКУ: пропустил `return` в методе `New()`. Бывает))

Answer (score 5):

> Есть ли в С++ аналог realloc из ванильного Си? Чтобы можно было менять размеры массива?

Аналога нет. Но в большинстве ситуаций `realloc` деградирует до `malloc`/`memcpy`/`free`. Выделяется новый блок памяти, содержимое старого блока копируется в его начало, старый блок памяти удаляется.

> будут ли правильно(т.е. с вызовом деструкторов) удаляться объекты при вызове delete[] array,если перед этим было array=realloc(....) ? И если нет, то как решить эту проблему?

Эту проблему нельзя решить, когда она возникла. Если вы не знаете как был выделен кусок памяти, у вас нет способа его удалить или изменить его размер. С самого начала должна быть строгая дисциплина. Для каждого указателя вы знаете как он был выделен и применяете только соответствующие функции. Или `calloc`/`malloc`/`realloc`/`free`, или `new[]/delete[]` (или `new/delete` если речь не о массивах). Указатель полученный вызовом в стиле `C` может обрабатываться только в стиле `C`. Указатель полученный вызовом в стиле `C++` может обрабатываться только в стиле `C++`.

> я знаю,что есть волшебный std::vector, но меня очень интересует реализация без примочек из STL.

Он не волшебный. Он написан на `C++` и хорошо показывает как из низкоуровнего управления памятью получить высокоуровневый безопасный интерфейс. И без дополнительных накладных расходов в большинстве ситуаций.

Comment: а если у объекта нет конструктора по умолчанию? (Который просто без параметров). То как перевыделять память? Я нашел примеры самодельного vector, которые мне даже понравились, но там для перевыделения памяти было просто arr=new T[++size], который должен вызывать консруктор без всего

Comment: Аллокатор выделяет сырую память. Её не надо конструировать. Когда вы помещаете в неё новый элемент, вызываете `placement new`. Удаление таких элементов - прямой вызов деструктора, без `delete`.

Comment: Вы бы задали вопрос "как написать простейший вектор на `malloc/free`".